# How to know for sure something was made in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flash

If you right-click on a game of movie in a website and see a box with the bottoim line "About Adobe Flash Player..." does that necessarily mean that the content was made with Flash (Either Flash Pro, Flash Builder, FDT, Flash Develop)?

Does it mean that the creators for sure used AS3, or could you in thery have an html5 or union project running in flash player?

Comment: Flash player only runs Flash content, not HTML5. If the Flash player is running you can be very confident that the content was made using Actionscript.

Comment: right click and check the source, use mozilla fire fox it will tell you what it is, most interactive rich media would be flash, if its just animation and basic transitions could be java/html or what have you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means the content is made in Flash. If you view source for the website, contents made in flash have .swf extension.

But the creators may not have used AS3, it may be made using AS2 if older.